# How to 'watch' newly created rows in local storage in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working to create a grid like component in VueJs. You can see the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/masade/nrb9f4j2/

- In the above fiddle the `<datacell>` component is used to allow inline edit for any cell.
- I am 'watch'-ing changes to the `rows` and saving them in local storage
- A newly created row is being pushed to parent object by `this.$parent.unshift(newrow)` in the `<addrow>` component

The problem is when I add a new row, though it is being added to the rows local storage it is not being watched for changes

Steps to replicate the issue (on JS fiddle):

- Click on Add Row and enter a name to add
- Once the row is added, click on the second column (year) and update it
- Any changes to newly added row is not being updated
- However if you refresh the page, and modify the same again, I am able to update it again.

Please help me understand if I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You stumbled into one of the [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in Vue. Vue cannot detect when you have added a property to an object using the index of that object.

You define `newrow` like this:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        newrow : {}
    }
},
```

which means that `newrow` has no properties. After that, you always add properties to `newrow` using an index, like here:

```
this.$parent.cols.map(function(col,index){
  if(typeof newrow[col.m] == "undefined")
    newrow[col.m] = "";
})
```

This means that Vue doesn't know about any of the properties you just added.

I added a method to your fiddle called `makeNewRow` which adds the properties you need to `newrow` correctly using the `$set` method.

```
makeNewRow(){
    this.newrow = {};
    this.$parent.cols.map((col,index) => this.$set(this.newrow, col.m, null))
},
```

Then I call it in `mounted` and in your `addRow` method. This fixes your bug. Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrb9f4j2/10/).

Note: there was an additional bug in your code that I fixed. If someone opened your app and did not *previously* have `grid-vue-local` in their local storage, then the `uid` for `gridStorage` would be zero, and the first row they added would have the id 0. To fix this I simply added

```
save: function (rows) {
  gridStorage.uid = rows.length
  localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(rows))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, been struggling to understand this for 2 days :)

Answer (score 1):

```
data(){
   return{
     items:localStorage.fetch()
   }
}


watch:{
   items:{
     handler:function(items){
        localStorage.save(items);
     },
     deep:true
   }
}
```

you can save in items,and watch items,if the items has changed,it will updata

Comment: I am doing the same, its applying the components to newly created rows. 

Line number 74 in js - https://jsfiddle.net/masade/nrb9f4j2/